# Jpa/Hibernate Odata $filter query fails in 2.0.10

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, odata

I have implemented in my spring boot project olingo-odata2 library . 
When I try this query in olingo-odata2 version 2.0.7

```
/api/v1/reports/Users?$filter=startswith(Description,'a') eq true
```

it works fine but in this version I cannot filtering in expanded property.
when I try the query in version 2.0.10 I get this error:

```
Query: `SELECT E1 FROM User E1 WHERE (E1.description LIKE CONCAT(?2,'%') ESCAPE '\' ) ORDER BY E1.id
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''\' order by user0_.id' at line 1

Comment: why you use `ESCAPE '\'` ?

Comment: Query is generated by Odata  ,in version 2.0.7 query dosen't contain  escape and it works fine

Comment: We found a solution but not the best, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122778/filter-not-working-in-jpa-olingo-2-0-11-with-mysql)